# Why was the verb put in simple past tense in this sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, subordinate-clauses

While reading [*Oxford Practice Grammar Advanced*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01A5U2U3E), I came across this sentence in one of the book's exercises:

> If she got up early enough and came downstairs, we had breakfast together.

I wonder why they used the simple past in the later clause instead of *would have*. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to be a wrong construction of the so called ‘third conditional’ (*if* + past → *would* + infinitive).

Comment: No it's fine. Change the sentence slightly: **If she rose early enough, we enjoyed breakfast together.** The sentence appears to be referring to a regular situation rather than a single event.

Comment: *If* sometimes means "whenever".

Comment: You might understand ***If*** here as equivalent to ***On [those] days when...***

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you all. Your comments were really helpful. You should consider giving this question an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a composite response, based on your suggestion:

No it's fine.
Change the sentence slightly: If she rose early enough, we enjoyed breakfast together.

The sentence appears to be referring to a regular situation rather than a single event. –
Ronald Sole 2 hours ago

If sometimes means "whenever". –
LawrenceC 2 hours ago

You might understand If here as equivalent to On [those] days when... –
FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica 2 hours ago